# Measuring front setbacks of buildings using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, vector, parcel

Does anyone know how to measure front setbacks using ArcGIS Pro?

[image]

I’d like to measure the distance from the front of the parcel to the nearest edge of the building of each lot. I’m aware of the Near tool but I’m having trouble figuring out how to measure front to back within each parcel and not just any nearest building to the front lot line.

Comment: Do you have any parameters relating to what defines the front of a plot? Included in that thinking how would you handle buildings that are not within a lot boundary?

Comment: Dissolve your cadastre, that way there is *only* the road frontage, then use near.

Comment: @KeaganAllan to determine the front of a plot I’ve been converting parcels to lines, exporting only lines that share a line with the ROW, then manually selecting the sections of each parcel line that abut the road for each parcel (these parcels has an attribute which is the road the frontage is located) I understand this isn’t the most efficient way but it’s the only way I know. Buildings not within a lot boundary I don’t care about but buildings crossing lot lines I’ve determined which building is in each lot by spatially joining buildings by center within each lot. Open to any improvements!

Comment: You're thinking too much. It really is a simple task: convert your parcels to polygons if they're not already - only the land parcels, get rid of the roads, then dissolve the polygon lots and convert the boundary to a line - now you have only the street frontage. You can use near on your building footprints to find the minimum distance from each building to the nearest road frontage - each building is going to be closer to its own frontage than frontage of the parcel next door... done! That process would also work just as well using only the road parcels.